How can I use workload identity pooling to succesfully push docker images to GCP?
I am setting up a service which I want to deploy to Cloud Run from Github Actions. However although the authentication action step is successful:
- name: Authenticate to Google Cloud
  id: auth
  uses: google-github-actions/auth@v2
  with:
  workload_identity_provider: "projects/<my-project>/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/<workload-identity-pool-name>/providers/<provider-id>"
  service_account: <service-account-email>

After I build my docker image and I attempt to push to GCR:
- name: Push Docker images
  run: |
   docker push gcr.io/${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}/<project-name>:${{ github.sha }}

I get the error:
There was a problem refreshing your current auth tokens: ('Unable to acquire impersonated credentials', '{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 403,\n    "message": "Permission \'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken\' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",\n    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",\n    "details": [\n      {\n        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",\n        "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",\n        "domain": "iam.googleapis.com",\n        "metadata": {\n          "permission": "iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken"\n        }\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n}\n')

In my GCP console I've set up:

A provider using the standard issuer for GH, a 'default audience' selection, mapping the attributes audience, actor and subject
A workload identity pool using this provider
A service account with the permissions I require (gets iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken via Workload Identity User)
A Principal with a principalSet entry for the repository where the GitHub Action itself lives

Could anyone shed some light on what I might be missing here?
I have checked to see if any organizational limits exist on permissions but can't find anything.
I had expected to be able to do something in my pipeline for debugging purposes to tell me exactly what permissions are applied to the authenticated user after the first step but have had no luck.

I'm not familiar with google-github-actions/auth@v2 but I suspect itt authenticates the environment for gcloud and/or possibly for Application Default Credentials. Container Registry (and Artifact Regsitry) rely on Docker's (!) Registry API to provide consistency for container tools across registries. For this reason you will probably (!) need to authenticate to GCR using one of the supported Authentication methods. It's possible there's a Google GitHub Action that implements this too.

Found the solution for anyone suffering from the same issue.
It was down to the attribute mappings in my provider.
Essentially, the principalSet I had added to service account looked something like:
 principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/projects/<myproject-number>/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/<my-pool-id>/attribute.repository/<repository-owner>/<repo-name> 

But my provider didn't have the mapping configured for attribute.repository.
So in the console adding attribute.repository -> assertion.repository mapping to my pool provider did the trick.
